# Yocto Raspberry Pi build with bitbake core-image-sato failed with -lEGL and -lGLESv2 were no found

Tags: raspberry-pi3, gstreamer, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am a newbie to yocto, trying to build a custom image for raspberry pi using bitbake core-image-sato. In the log attached below  I can see that   -lEGL  and -lGLESv2 were not found while building image. But Could not figure out how to fix it?

ERROR: gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-1.14.4-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed

```
/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build$ bitbake core-image-sato
Loading cache: 100% |########################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01
Loaded 3552 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |######################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Parsing of 2437 .bb files complete (2436 cached, 1 parsed). 3552 targets, 150 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.42.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "ubuntu-18.04"
TARGET_SYS           = "aarch64-oe-linux"
MACHINE              = "raspberrypi3-64"
DISTRO               = "nodistro"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "nodistro.0"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "aarch64 cortexa53 crc"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "warrior:f65b24e9ca0918a4ede70ea48ed8b7cc4620f07f"
meta-oe              
meta-multimedia      
meta-networking      
meta-python          
meta-perl            
meta-gnome           
meta-xfce            = "warrior:a24acf94d48d635eca668ea34598c6e5c857e3f8"
meta-raspberrypi     = "warrior:5551792e642d6cc32e22dfe6dbfd29ac3e2390cd"

Initialising tasks: 100% |###################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:04
Sstate summary: Wanted 1562 Found 0 Missed 1562 Current 460 (0% match, 22% complete)
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-1.14.4-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-1.14.4-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/temp/log.do_compile.6117)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/temp/log.do_compile.6117
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-64', 'arm-common', 'arm-64', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'aarch64-linux', 'common']
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 6
| make  all-recursive
| make[1]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build'
| Making all in pkgconfig
| make[2]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/pkgconfig'
| make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
| make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/pkgconfig'
| Making all in gst-libs
| make[2]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs'
| Making all in gst
| make[3]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst'
| make -C tag
| make -C fft
| make -C video
| make -C app
| make[4]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/video'
| make  all-am
| make[4]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/app'
| make[4]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/tag'
| make  all-am
| make  all-am
| make[4]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/fft'
| make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
| make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
| make[4]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/rtp'
| Making all in sdp
| make[4]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/sdp'
| make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
| make[4]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/sdp'
| Making all in rtsp
| make[4]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/rtsp'
| make  all-am
| make[5]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/rtsp'
| make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
| make[5]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/rtsp'
| make[4]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/rtsp'
| Making all in video
| make[4]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/video'
| make  all-am
| make[5]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/video'
| make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
| make[5]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/video'
| make[4]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/video'
| Making all in pbutils
| make[4]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/pbutils'
| make  all-am
| make[5]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/pbutils'
| make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
| make[5]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/pbutils'
| make[4]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/pbutils'
| Making all in riff
| make[4]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/riff'
| make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
| make[4]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/riff'
| Making all in app
| make[4]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/app'
| make  all-am
| make[5]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/app'
| make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
| make[5]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/app'
| make[4]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/app'
| Making all in allocators
| make[4]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/allocators'
| make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
| make[4]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/allocators'
| Making all in gl
| make[4]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/gl'
| Making all in glprototypes
| make[5]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/gl/glprototypes'
| make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
| make[5]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/gl/glprototypes'
| Making all in x11
| make[5]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/gl/x11'
| make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
| make[5]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/gl/x11'
| Making all in egl
| make[5]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/gl/egl'
| make[5]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
| make[5]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/gl/egl'
| make[5]: Entering directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/gl'
| ../../../aarch64-oe-linux-libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link aarch64-oe-linux-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-a53+crc --sysroot=/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot -DGST_EXPORTS -I../../../../gst-plugins-base-1.14.4/gst-libs -I../../../gst-libs -pthread -I/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -I/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -pthread -I/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -I/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -pthread -I/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -I/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include  -fno-strict-aliasing -DG_THREADS_MANDATORY -DG_DISABLE_CAST_CHECKS -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Waddress -Wno-multichar -Wnested-externs       -fvisibility=hidden -I/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/vc -I/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/interface -I/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/interface/vcos -I/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fmacro-prefix-map=/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0=/usr/src/debug/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0=/usr/src/debug/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot=                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=   -no-undefined -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -version-info 1404:0:1404 -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -o libgstgl-1.0.la -rpath /usr/lib libgstgl_1.0_la-gstgldisplay.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglcontext.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstgldebug.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglbasememory.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglbuffer.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglmemory.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglmemorypbo.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglrenderbuffer.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglbufferpool.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglfilter.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglformat.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglbasefilter.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglshader.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglshaderstrings.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglsl.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglslstage.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglcolorconvert.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglupload.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglwindow.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglapi.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglfeature.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglutils.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglframebuffer.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglsyncmeta.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglviewconvert.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstgloverlaycompositor.lo libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglquery.lo ../../../gst-libs/gst/video/libgstvideo-1.0.la ../../../gst-libs/gst/allocators/libgstallocators-1.0.la -lgmodule-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0 -lgstbase-1.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0  -lGLESv2 -lX11-xcb -lX11 -lxcb -lEGL -lEGL -lGLESv2   x11/libgstgl-x11.la       egl/libgstgl-egl.la
| aarch64-oe-linux-libtool: link: aarch64-oe-linux-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-a53+crc --sysroot=/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstgldisplay.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglcontext.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstgldebug.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglbasememory.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglbuffer.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglmemory.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglmemorypbo.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglrenderbuffer.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglbufferpool.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglfilter.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglformat.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglbasefilter.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglshader.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglshaderstrings.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglsl.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglslstage.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglcolorconvert.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglupload.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglwindow.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglapi.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglfeature.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglutils.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglframebuffer.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglsyncmeta.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglviewconvert.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstgloverlaycompositor.o .libs/libgstgl_1.0_la-gstglquery.o  -Wl,--whole-archive x11/.libs/libgstgl-x11.a egl/.libs/libgstgl-egl.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  ../../../gst-libs/gst/video/.libs/libgstvideo-1.0.so -lorc-0.4 ../../../gst-libs/gst/allocators/.libs/libgstallocators-1.0.so -lm -lgmodule-2.0 -lgstbase-1.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lX11-xcb -lX11 -lxcb -lEGL -lGLESv2  -mcpu=cortex-a53+crc --sysroot=/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot -pthread -pthread -pthread -O2 -g -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -pthread   -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,libgstgl-1.0.so.0 -o .libs/libgstgl-1.0.so.0.1404.0
| /media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-oe-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-oe-linux/gcc/aarch64-oe-linux/8.3.0/ld: skipping incompatible /media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libEGL.so when searching for -lEGL
| /media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-oe-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-oe-linux/gcc/aarch64-oe-linux/8.3.0/ld: skipping incompatible /media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libEGL.so when searching for -lEGL
| /media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-oe-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-oe-linux/gcc/aarch64-oe-linux/8.3.0/ld: cannot find -lEGL
| /media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-oe-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-oe-linux/gcc/aarch64-oe-linux/8.3.0/ld: skipping incompatible /media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libGLESv2.so when searching for -lGLESv2
| /media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-oe-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-oe-linux/gcc/aarch64-oe-linux/8.3.0/ld: skipping incompatible /media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libGLESv2.so when searching for -lGLESv2
| /media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-oe-linux/../../libexec/aarch64-oe-linux/gcc/aarch64-oe-linux/8.3.0/ld: cannot find -lGLESv2
| collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
| Makefile:897: recipe for target 'libgstgl-1.0.la' failed
| make[5]: *** [libgstgl-1.0.la] Error 1
| make[5]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/gl'
| Makefile:1249: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
| make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
| make[4]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst/gl'
| Makefile:629: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
| make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
| make[3]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs/gst'
| Makefile:594: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
| make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
| make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build/gst-libs'
| Makefile:718: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
| make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/build'
| Makefile:649: recipe for target 'all' failed
| make: *** [all] Error 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/rpi64-build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/1.14.4-r0/temp/log.do_compile.6117)
ERROR: Task (/media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base_1.14.4.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2019 tasks of which 2009 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base_1.14.4.bb:do_compile
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Tried cleaning gstreamer1.0 and rebuilding it using

```
bitbake -c cleanall gstreamer1.0
bitbake  gstreamer1.0
```

which run with no errors but when trying to build a image using core-image-sato getting the same errors as above.

Also tried to list -lEGL  and -lGLESv2 as dependency in gstreamer1.0-plugins-base_1.14.4.bb file.
Does someone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

```
 Loading cache: 100% |########################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 3552 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |######################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Parsing of 2437 .bb files complete (2436 cached, 1 parsed). 3552 targets, 150 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'lGLESv2' (but /media/hemanth/1681a4c7-3532-4108-a811-7a46dbe5ca8b/yoctoRpi3/poky-warrior/meta/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-base_1.14.4.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'opencv' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['opencv', 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-base', 'lGLESv2']
ERROR: Required build target 'core-image-sato' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['core-image-sato', 'opencv', 'gstreamer1.0-plugins-base', 'lGLESv2']
```

Comment: Does adding
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " egl gles gles2"
in build/config/local.conf helps?

Comment: It did not work, getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had deleted the whole build directory and then recreated a new build director using `source oe-init-build-env` and was able to build an image with `bitbake core-image-sato` with no errors. Assuming it's because of some error in the catch data.